# End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed. SerializationException

Tags: serialization, c#-4.0, generics, binaryformatter

Anyone can help with this method? I have a generic method for deserializing files to types.

```
public static T DeserializeFromFile<T>(string fileName) where T : class
{
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        return null;

    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any idea why I get this SerializationException?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly because the file wasn't written correctly... You also don't need to seek the stream to 0 - when you open for Open it's already there.

Comment: It's problem on serialization, the type is an externa assembly type where has no Serializable attributes.

Comment: @George: how did you serialize it then; because this exception is throwing at the deserialization process, so I assumed that the object has been successfully serialized before..

Answer (score 2):

Try remove `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`, However how are you serialize the data anyway, maybe there is a problem there too? an appropriate method looks like:

```
public static bool TrySerializeToFile<T>(string fileName, T data) where T : class
{
    bool operationSucceed = false;
    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            formatter.Serialize(stream, data);

            operationSucceed = true;
        }
    }
    catch
    { }

    return operationSucceed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use the Stream.Position Property? in other words instead of this statement:

```cs
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

That statement:

```cs
stream.Position=0;
```